# Double format with prefix whitespaces

Tags: java

I'm wondering, if there is better way, how to format double value in Java. I wanted to add white spaces before value, and '0' values after value.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] a = {1, 10, 100, -1, -10, -100, 1.1, 1.11, -1.1, -1.11, 100123, -123124.1233};
        for (double v : a) {
            System.out.println("[" + formatDouble(v, 15, 10) + "]");
        }
    }

    public static String formatDouble(double value, int prefix, int suffix) {
        String s = String.format("%." + suffix + "f", value);

        String spaces = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < prefix + suffix - s.length(); i++) {
            spaces += " ";
        }

        return spaces + s;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[             1.0000000000]
[            10.0000000000]
[           100.0000000000]
[            -1.0000000000]
[           -10.0000000000]
[          -100.0000000000]
[             1.1000000000]
[             1.1100000000]
[            -1.1000000000]
[            -1.1100000000]
[        100123.0000000000]
[       -123124.1233000000]
```

If I use

```
 System.out.println("{" + new Formatter().format(Locale.FRANCE, "%+15.10f", v) + "]");
```

output will be:

```
[  +1,0000000000]
[ +10,0000000000]
[+100,0000000000]
[  -1,0000000000]
[ -10,0000000000]
[-100,0000000000]
[  +1,1000000000]
[  +1,1100000000]
[  -1,1000000000]
[  -1,1100000000]
[+100123,0000000000]
[-123124,1233000000]
```

And that is not, what I want.
My code is working, But I think, there is better solution, but I did not find it.

Comment: What is your question? It looks like your code does what you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "and '0' values after value"? Could you show example/comparison of what you have now vs what you want to achieve?

Comment: If your code is working but you are looking for *any* improvements then it better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Consider deleting it from here and posting it there with clear description of what are you after.

Comment: Seems you just want to make the field length in the format larger: e.g. `%20.10f`.

Answer (score 0):

From [`Formatter` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dndec):

`// Optional locale as the first argument can be used to get
   // locale-specific formatting of numbers.  The precision and width can be
   // given to round and align the value.
   formatter.format(Locale.FRANCE, "e = %+10.4f", Math.E);
   // -> "e =    +2,7183"`